# Undefined reference to `main' when using makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have four files `list.h` `list.c` `test_list.c` `Makefile`

**list.h**

```
#ifndef List_H
#define List_H
#endif
/*nothing else*/
```

**list.c**

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*nothing else*/
```

**test_list.c**

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdio.h>   
int main(){
    return 0;
}
/*nothing else*/
```

**Makefile**

```
CC=cc
CXX=CC
CCFLAGS= -g -std=c99 -Wall -Werror

all: list test_list

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $<

test_list: list.o test_list.o
    $(CC) -o test_list list.o test_list.o

test: test_list
    ./test_list

clean:
    rm -f core *.o test_list
```

when I input make in shell, here comes the error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
>       /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':(.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main'
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       make: *** [list] Error 1

What is wrong here?

Comment: As an aside, your `"%.o` rule does the same as the implicit one. But you should probably make one for `list.o`, to add a dependency to `list.h`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not specified a rule for building the target `list`, so `make` is inferring the following rule, which fails because you do not have a `main` function in your `list.c`.

```
cc     list.c   -o list
```

Since `list` should not be built as an executable anyways (no main), simply do not try to build `list` as a target in your `Makefile`, and then `test_list` will build correctly.

```
all:  test_list
```

Comment: Thanks, this exactly solves my problem, my teacher likes to write `all:  test_list test`, is this more standard? I do not know whether the targets should all be the binary files after linking.

Comment: @brickmanjim, Yes, It is conventional to use the target `all` with the actual binary targets as dependencies.

Comment: I mean the second target `test` in `all: test_list test`,  it is not a binary file but it is also in `all`

Comment: @brickmanjim, I have seen it both ways, but I have seen the `test` target independent of the `all` target more often. That is, the default build target does not also perform tests.

Answer (score 3):

You defined a target **list** but did not define a rule for it. So make tried its implicit rule to generate this target rule by emitting the following command

```
cc     list.c   -o list
```

so that you got the linking errors since there is no a symbol named main in list.c

You can see how the implicit rules work just by running

```
make -r
```

Answer (score 2):

You're already building your program as `test_list`, so no need for a `list` target.

Change:

```
all: list test_list
```

To:

```
all: test_list
```